# Add a tab onto a UITabBar which performes a method rather than a new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm wanting to fire an action when you click a certain tab (say tab `[index] 3`) rather than show a new `viewController`.

I can't find a way of doing this, is there a method for this I can implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement `– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in such way:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    BOOL shouldSelect = YES;
    NSInteger tabToIgnore = 3;
    if ([tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == tabToIgnore) {
        shouldSelect = NO;
        [self performSpecificAction];
    }
    return shouldSelect;
}
```

When you initialise `UITabBarController` object with list of view controllers you can use simply `[[UIViewController alloc] init]` for index 3.

Comment: Hey thanks for adding to the post - a question, using this method am I supposed to add the tab through the storyboard or add the tab programatically? At the moment, I have 4 viewcontrollers (all linked to the tabbed view controller) which has the respective tab item. The last one (4th) needs to not display however run a method as said above. Should this 4th tab be added programatically or should it be as it is a blank viewcontroller in the storyboard? At current, the above code doesnt fire, I have put an `NSLog()` in the code looking for any triggers

Comment: @Jack4 If you use story board then it is simpler for you to provide 4-th view controller in story board. Use `UIViewController` as class for this view controller. Also of course you need set delegate to your `UITabBarController` object.

Comment: Okay thanks, so the code above should go on the class for the viewcontroller rather than on the class for the tabbarcontroller?

Comment: @Jack4 This code should go to class that is delegate of your `UITabBarController` object (for example AppDelegate). You need set it by yourself.

Comment: So, on the class I have for the `UITabBarController` I have input the method above, with 2 NSLog()'s on, inside the if and outside the if. This isnt triggering - have I missed something?

Comment: @Jack4 I think that you missed to set delegate to `UITabBarController`. For example if you have link to tab bar controller object in `AppDelegate` class then you need write there like this: `self.tabBarController.delegate = self`. Also add my code from answer to `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: Sorry - im pretty new to using delegates. Inside `AppDelegate.m` I have put your method, where do I put `self.tabBarController.delegate = self`? I get errors when I put it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, and also errors when i put it inside the method you wrote above

Comment: @Jack4 Try this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method: `UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Comment: Ahh thank you! I need to read up on how this works - thank you very much!